# Beautiful Soup web scraping with CSS selectors

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape 11 fields from a standard SEC filing on EDGAR (SEC.gov) and return them to a simple dictionary. When I run the code below, 7 of the fields work fine, but 4 of the fields (named in the code as "Director", "Officer", "Person", and "Ticker") return an empty list value in spite of showing actual text in these fields on the page and I cannot figure out how to resolve. I obtained the CSS selector info for these fields using DevTools in Chrome and viewing the Elements tab while on the page I'm trying to scrape. One thing to note is that these 4 fields have longer CSS selectors than the ones that work correctly (i.e. the "tree" describing the location on the page is longer than the others) so I feel there must be something I'm doing wrong syntax-wise in pointing to these 4 fields.

As a side note I'm new to Python, and early in the process of working on this I learned that with Beautiful Soup the CSS selector references must use "nth-of-type" instead of "nth-child", so I've already made those changes to my code.

I'm at a loss as to why these 4 fields won't return the data shown on the form, while the other 7 work fine. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Note: I'm using Python 3.

```
import bs4, requests, pprint

def getFormData(form4url):
    res = requests.get(form4url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    # scrape the data from each field of the SEC Form 4 document. Each field is identified by its
    # CSS selector from the web page's html (viewed using DevTools -> Elements tab in Chrome)
    person = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr > td > a')
    ticker = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(2) > span.FormData')
    director = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > span')
    officer = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1)')
    security = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(3) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > span')
    date = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(3) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(2) > span')
    tCode = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(3) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(4)')
    qtyTrans = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(3) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(6) > span.FormData')
    transType = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(3) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(7) > span')
    price = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(3) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(8) > span.FormData')
    qtyAfter = soup.select('body > table:nth-of-type(3) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(9) > span')

    return {'Person':person,'Ticker':ticker,'Director':director,'Officer':officer, \
            'Security':security,'Date':date, 'Trans Code':tCode, 'Quantity':qtyTrans, \
            'Trans Type':transType,'Price':price,'Qty After':qtyAfter}

# this is the website to scrape
userLink = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1539638/000120919118040737/xslF345X03/doc4.xml'
dataDict = getFormData(userLink)

# following just cleans up values in dict by removing html from scraped fields (lists of
# strings), leaving only the visible text   
for key,value in dataDict.items():
    if len(value) > 0:
        dataDict[key] = dataDict[key][0].text.strip()      

pprint.pprint(dataDict)
```

Comment: Any recommendations on a more appropriate forum for me to post this question?

Answer (score 0):

The correct CSS selectors for `Person`, `Ticker`, `Director`, and `Officer` are:

```
person: "table:nth-of-type(2) > tr > td > table"
ticker: "table:nth-of-type(2) > tr > td:nth-of-type(2) > span:nth-of-type(2)"
director: "table:nth-of-type(2) > tr > td:nth-of-type(3) > table > tr > td"
officer: "table:nth-of-type(2) > tr > td:nth-of-type(3) > table > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td"
```

Here is demo using Node.js, `x-ray`, and the example link you provided: https://codesandbox.io/s/j489wlyzmw

The demo doesn't return any value for `Officer` because `Officer` is not set.